# why outcome object in FutureTask is non-volatile?

Tags: java, concurrency, lock-free

I read FutureTask class in jsr166, found that outcome object is non-volatile, the comments in code is "non-volatile, protected by state reads/writes" line 75, the state is volatile int. I have read Java Memory Model from [Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html), but not found the accurate answer. Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

consider this program:

```
volatile int state;  

Integer   result;

void succeed(Integer result)
    if(state==PENDING)              vr0
        this.result = result;        w1
        state = DONE;               vw1

Integer peekResult()
    if(state==DONE)                 vr2 
        return result;               r2
    return null;
```

If volatile read `vr2` sees `DONE`, it means it happens after volatile write `vw1`. So we have happens-before relationships:  `w1 -> vw1 -> vr2 -> r2`. Therefore write `w1` is visible to read `r2`.

However `succeed()` isn't thread safe, since `vr0` and `vw1` are not atomic. If we use CAS

```
void succeed(Integer result)
    if( compareAndSet(state, PENDING, DONE) )      vr0+vw0
        this.result = result;                       w1
```

it fixes the atomicity issue. However, now `w1` isn't necessarily visible to `r2`. The memory barrier effect of CAS is kind of like

```
void succeed(Integer result)
    if(state==PENDING)         vr0
        state=DONE;            vw0
        this.result = result;   w1
```

We have here `vw0 -> vr2 -> r2`, but `w1` is not on the chain, there is no `w1 -> r2`

We must do the volatile write `state=DONE` after `w1` to establish the happens-before chain.

```
void succeed(Integer result)
    if(state==PENDING)            vr0
        state=TMP;                vw0
        this.result = result;      w1
        state=DONE;               vw1
```

or in CAS

```
void succeed(Integer result)
    if( compareAndSet(state, PENDING, TMP) )       vr0+vw0
        this.result = result;                       w1
        state=DONE;                                vw1
```